# Properties in Obj - JS

Tags: javascript, object

What is the difference between `myObj[property]` and `myObj['property']` and the way they access things?

```
var key = 'property';

var myObj = {
  key: [2,3,6,8],
  property: ["matt", "black", "rodel"]
};
```

Also is there a big difference using `quoted` and `unquoted` property?

Comment: The difference between `myObj[property]` and `myObj['property']` is the same as the difference between `property` and `'property'`.

Comment: If you asked "what's the difference between `myObj[key]` and `myObj['property']`" that would make more sense. The answer is no difference. They both are able to access the `property` value in the object. One using the value of a variable, the other using straight string access.

Comment: It sounds like you know that an Object's property can be accessed by either `person.name` or `person['name']`. However, `person[name]` is basically a mixture of the two and will only refer to the same thing if `name` is indeed storing the string `"name"`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you can't do `obj[property]` unless `property` is a variable that is holding a string, you can either do `obj['property']`, `obj[property]` (property must be a string) or `obj.property` :

```js
var key = 'property';//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                                      //     ^
var myObj = {                         //     ^
  key: [2,3,6,8],                     //     ^
  property: ["matt", "black", "rodel"]//     ^
};                                    //     ^
console.log(myObj[key]); // key is a string  ^, this is neither myObj.key nor myObj['key']
console.log(myObj['property']);
console.log(myObj.property);
```

Note that `obj[property]` is not necessarily `obj['property']` or `obj.property`, it depends on what value the string variable `property` has, in your example the string variable `key` had the value `"property"`, and `obj[key]` returned the object's property.

Answer (score 0):

As few already mentioned in the comments, `'property'` is a string literal which is used as object key.

Now `property` can possibly be a variable and have some other value, like:

```
var property = 'key';
myObj[property] === myObj['key']; // true
```

would be a `true` statement.

Generally it is a good idea to use object keys directly, not using the `array` notation.

```
// preferred usage
myObj.key;
myObj.property;

// not recommended to use on objects, but only on arrays
myObj['key'];
myObj['property'];
```

But if your properties are dynamic and you don't know the value upfront, then it's OK to use the array notation:

```
['key', 'property'].forEach( function( keyName ) {
    console.log( keyName + ' => ' + myObj[keyName] )
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You've inadvertently provided the perfect example code:

```js
var key = 'property';

var myObj = {
  key: [2,3,6,8],   // this line does *not* use the key variable!
  property: ["matt", "black", "rodel"]
};

console.log(myObj[key]);   // myObj['property'] -> myObj.property
console.log(myObj['key']); //                      myObj.key
```

Note however that when *defining* an Object literal, using quotes or not for the key doesn't make a difference (provided the key doesn't have spaces or the like).

```
var obj = { "key": 123 };
```

and

```
var obj = { key: 123 };
```

are interchangeable.